# Error Reading From A file Inside A Directory

Tags: python

I am trying to read files, inside a folder, reason is the number of files inside the folder is not fixed, but if there are 3 text folder, I have to read all the 3 files if 4 all the 4 text files.

Here is the code I'm trying to use, but comes up with an IOError:

```
for i in os.listdir("./RecordFolder"):
    print i
```

Output is:
    record1.txt
    record2.txt

Now the problem is reading the files:

```
for files in os.listdir("./RecordFolder"):
    filecontent = open(files).readlines()
    for lines in filecontent:
    print lines
```

Output:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'record.txt'
```

Need some help here, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `os.listdir()` only returns the file names, not the full paths, so you should use `os.path.join()` to add the directory names:

```
directory = "./RecordFolder"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(os.path.join(directory, filename)) as f:
        for line in f:
            print line
```

(Also note that you shouldn't use `file.readlines()` for simply iterating over the lines of the files, and that your code fails to close the file.  These problems are fixed in the code above.)

Comment: yes.. :D this is why i like stackoverflow, get to know lot of ways to achieve the same thing :) thanks @Sven Marnach

Comment: I have got another small question, if the records.txt are huge files in MB is it a good idea to use for loop? or is there any other way? @mgilson

Comment: @Whiskey -- It depends a little bit on what you want/need to get out of the lines.  If you're building a list out of the information, maybe you could use a `list-comprehension` or `map`.  But whether this is actually a good idea depends a lot on how difficult the processing actually is.  For example: `[line.split()[0] for line in f]` isn't too bad, but if you don't actually want to build a list, then just use a `for` loop.  The performance isn't going to be very different.

Comment: I have to think about performance.. basically this is a small application that I m trying to make for my school, just for practice .. where there would be names of students in class. so 10 class with 3 sections each with around 100 students in each class.

And it has to read the files and find out a given name, duplicates will be there, but then it will be sorted with some another criteria.. so the text files will be big in size.. hence I am little concerned.

Comment: Ok in other words, U meant.. 3000 wont create a problem if using for loop :) thanks :)

Comment: @Whiskey -- Well, I meant that performance (probably) isn't an issue.  Basically, do whatever is the most easy to read/comprehend.  As a side note, don't forget to accept an answer (Based on community feedback, I would advise you accept Sven's).

Answer (score 2):

`os.listdir` only returns the name of the files inside the folder.  Not the entire path.

You want something like:

```
directory = os.path.join(os.curdir, "RecordFolder")
for files in os.listdir(directory):
    filecontent = open( os.path.join(directory, files) ).readlines()
    for lines in filecontent:
        print lines
```

But this isn't the best way to get the lines from a file.  Look into python context managers -- specifically:

```
with open(filename) as f:
     for line in f:
         print line
```

This makes sure that the file is properly closed (even in the event of an error -- barring a segmentation fault in the interpreter itself or something bizarre like that).